# Tag temporary changes in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

We are working with Mercurial for a year now, but today a question arised about how to handle (or better: identify) files that have been edited temporarely.

The user that asked me how to do it is currently switching from ClearCase to Mercurial. In ClearCase you could use 'hijacked files' to distinguish between changes that should be commited, and changes that should be reverted.

In Mercurial (using TortoiseHg) I couldn't find any similar solution to achieve this.

Long story short: How can you distinguish between files that were edited temporarely during development from files that were edited for getting committed.

What is your advice / best practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: What does temporarily even mean? If they're not for the check-in then they shouldn't be checked in, period. There should be no changes to revert.

Comment: The user maintains an old Fortran-Project for calculating the physics inside a rolling mill. The temporary changes are required during development, for testing purposes but have to be reverted before pushing the changes. This affects something between 10 and 100 files. Having to look into each of them to decide whether it contains a wanted or unwanted change is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) patch for files with temporary changes, commits for permanent changes (user must know, which files are in every category)

On commit, user can exclude some modified files from changeset and use later these files for refreshing (applied) patch.

Forgetting these changes is just unapply patch

Comment: Ok, this is not exactly what we wanted, but may be the best what can be done with Mercurial. Thank you.